# Accessing Oracle database in android application

Tags: android, oracle

I want to access an oracle database in my android app.  I searched through many tutorials but didn't find the proper one.  Can someone suggest me some good tutorials to access oracle in android.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You should consider for mobile server, a clear product from Oracle designed specifically mobile devices. It includes a full synchronization engine that can either run stand alone for example or be controlled from inside your app via API.

Check [Oracle Database Mobile Server 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html?origref=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-lite/lite-mobile-server-083863.html) it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the mobile domain its not wise and most probably not possible to connect mysql or oracle database using JDBC or ODBC driver as they are heavy and not designed to run on mobile OS.

Go for light weight web services like SOAP or RESTful ...
These webservice returns xml or json in response. parse it on android side and use the data.

Comment: kosap2 in android is cool i managed to call procedures with CRUD operations and get resultset for search WOOw

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have proxy/application server that is talking to oracle and can deliver the data to android via convenient format like json or xml.

Direct connection to the oracle database server would require:

1. Steady network connection
2. Oracle driver, that is quite heavy